# Problems positioning multiple d3 graphs on html page

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I need to position multiple (ultimately 4, but I am starting with two here) d3 graphs on one web page. Following [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/07/arranging-more-than-one-d3js-graph-on.html), I created two divs:

```
<div id="donut"></div>
<div id="line-graph"></div>
```

And then I appended the graphs to their respective divs like so:

```
var svg = d3.select("#line-graph").append("svg")
```

AND

```
var svg = d3.select("#donut").append("svg")
```

Yet, they are still on top of each other on the page.  What am I missing?

I know there are other people who have had this problem, but a lot of those questions are either unanswered, or the answer did not solve my problem.  You can see what I am talking about [here](http://www.pitt.edu/~kac232/finalproject/neighborhood_profile.html).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your scripts declare global variables named 'svg' and then reference this global variable in the callback after the file is loaded. If you inspect your graphs, you'll see that they are actually both on the same SVG element and the SVG element that the line graph *should* be on is empty.

You need to rename your variables in your second script so that they have different names than the variables in the first script.

Comment: One more question about this, actually.  Any thoughts on why the years are now missing from the x-axis?  This is the [original](http://www.pitt.edu/~kac232/finalproject/linegraph_resize.html) and this is [now](http://www.pitt.edu/~kac232/finalproject/neighborhood_profile.html).  I only just noticed it but I think it actually went missing when I first appended to divs.  I've been styling the page but I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Your x-axis is outside of the bounds of your SVG. Your SVG has height 260px, the g container is then translated down 20px, and the x-axis is translated down 260px. So the *top* of the x-axis is at 280px, which is below the bottom of the SVG. Note: In both Safari and Chrome (and I assume in FF) you can right-click "Inspect element" to browse through the generated HTML/SVG and investigate problems like this.

Comment: Ethan, thanks for the help and the suggestion to use inspect element.  I'm really new at this so it's very helpful.

Comment: No problem. SVG's overflow behavior is a little weird for people used to standard HTML elements, in my experience. Welcome to the wonderful world of d3 :-)